# How to read Json File with many diferent (key, value pairs) in Spark Scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a json File that looks like this:

```
{
item-1: {propertyA: "blabla", propertyB: "blabla", propertyC: "blabla"}, 
item-2: {propertyA: "blabla", propertyB: "blabla", propertyC: "blabla"},
   ...      ...        ...      ...        ...        ...       ...    ,
item-30000: {propertyA: "blabla", propertyB: "blabla", propertyC: "blabla"}
}
```

How can i load this to Spark? I am using Scala and IntelijIDEA.

It takes too much time and in the end i get errors like:

```
WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. 
This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
```

* The error is after i tried to explicit infer the schema by creating 30.000 StructFields in a struct-Type.
By Implicitly infering the schema I have similar but bigger problems...
Any help appreciated.

*Actually I have One big line with all of these records. I wrote it like that for better understanding.

- After 30 min it ends like that:

  ```
  /* 3002032      apply20000_14999(i);
  /* 3002033      result.setTotalSize(holder.totalSize());
  /* 3002034      return result;
  /* 3002035    }
  /* 3002036    }
  org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Constant pool for class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.
  GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection has grown past JVM limit of 0xFFFF
  ```

Comment: can you show us your code as how you are reading the file to dataframe ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan my code is very simple: val myDF = sparkSession.read.json("...path...").cache()  Either implicit or explicit inference it takes forever and after 30min or more it throws errors.

Comment: you said you applied the schema . where did you apply the schema?

Comment: Explicitly by the .schema(mySchema)

Comment: is your json multiple lines or single line? valid json should be of `{"item-1":{"propertyA":"blabla","propertyB":"blabla","propertyC":"blabla"},"item-2":{"propertyA":"blabla","propertyB":"blabla","propertyC":"blabla"},"item-30000":{"propertyA":"blabla","propertyB":"blabla","propertyC":"blabla"}}` type

Comment: It is like the one you specify above. It is a valid Json. I passed it through validatior. It just has 30.000 unique ids with 5 properties per id. I am working with Intelij -> memory problems. I run it through sbt with 4g memory -> 30 min+ -> and the above problem... :(((

Comment: try persist and spill the data to disk instead of memory. I guess its a memory issue as you are using cache.